# C programming - Matrix index X and Y

Tags: c, matrix

Hey everyone I am working on making a matrix to display some user input, if anyone could please help that would be awesome!.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int m, n, c, d, matrix[10][10];

   printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of matrix\n");
   scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
   printf("Enter the elements of the matrix\n");

   for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
      for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ )
         scanf("%d", &matrix[c][d]);

   for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
   {
      for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ )
         printf("%d\t%d\t", c, d);

               printf("\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
my output: 
Enter the number of rows and columns of matrix
3 3
Enter the elements of the matrix
a b c

0   0   0   1   0   2   
1   0   1   1   1   2   
2   0   2   1   2   2
```

I have no idea why it's displaying numbers, and why there is double columns and rows. All i need is:

```
A B C 
A B C
A B C
```

Very confused, thanks guys
:) :) :) :) :)

Comment: you are assigning charaters to integer type Array.

Comment: Note: check return value of `scanf`, otherwise the program might do weirdest things (including Undefined Behaviour) if you give it invalid input.

Comment: "*I have no idea why it's displaying numbers, and why there is double columns and rows.*" because you coded it this way: `printf("%d\t%d\t", c, d);`

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 mistakes:

1) You should use `scanf` with `%c` to read the elements.

2) In your printing loop, you should print `matrix[c][d]` with `%c`

Comment: dont you think he is using Integer matrix to store characters, which is not right!!

Answer (score 0):

Find the corrected code here

```
int main()
{
    int m, n, c, d;
   char  matrix[10][10]; //Fix1

   printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of matrix\n");
   scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
   getchar();//Fix2
   printf("Enter the elements of the matrix\n");

   for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
      for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ ){
         scanf("%c", &matrix[c][d]);//Fix3
            getchar();//Fix4

}
   for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
   {
      for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ )
         printf("%c ", matrix[c][d]);//Fix4

               printf("\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

solve the warnings during the compilation. To enable warnings use -Wall in compilation command.